# What has been the effect of being able to fast forward commercials?

Tags: commercial

To keep this on-topic, this is not about 'commercials' - rather television production and economic effects (see tag description) of majority viewers being able to skip commercials.

Every person I know who watches television now has the ability to pause/ff/rewind recorded shows.  I watch on tv.google, and wait a bit after the show is airing so I can FFwd through commercials, with the exception of sports.

**Has there been a noticeable effect in the television industry due to this?**  e.g. a lesser cost for commercials to air, et. al.

Comment: This certainly feels too broad. The fact that one *can* FF through a commercial due to technology would in no way affect the cost of the advertiser paying to have it shown. The broadcaster doesn't care whether you can FF or not.

Comment: I think the ability to record shows and watch them later (while fast-forwarding the ads) would have much more of a noticeable effect, in terms of reduced viewing figures.

Comment: Yes. Faster tv shows to make more space for ads. Seinfield being speed up is one example. Advertisers pay for the time during initial "nonskippable" airing. Anything more is just a gain on their side.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Thanks, I'll try to narrow it down, but in specific, has this been noticed in the industry?  Since I probably haven't seen a single commercial in well over five years (except when watching a live game), I imagine I'm not alone.  I can't find any publication or mention about the effect of this, so I'm asking movies.se if someone in the industry has experienced this.